# How to find an child element in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use Angular js in my app and I have a question regarding the click event

in my html

```
<div ng-click='clickMe()' ng-controller='testCtrl'>
   <img src='test.png'/>
   more codes...
</div>
```

controller.js

```
.controller('testCtrl', function(){
   $scope.clickMe = function(){
       $(this).find('img').attr('src','newImg.png')
   }
}
```

I want to be able to use `$(this).find()` method to find the images or other elements but I am not sure hot wo do that in Angular. Can someone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Angular, you want to avoid doing DOM manipulation in a controller but instead take advantage of databinding to do this...

```
<div ng-click='clickMe()' ng-controller='testCtrl'>
   <img ng-src='{{imgSrc}}'/>
   more codes...
</div>
```

Controller

```
.controller('testCtrl', function(){
   $scope.imgSrc = 'test.png';
   $scope.clickMe = function(){
       $scope.imgSrc = 'newImg.png';
   }
}
```